Assigning order attribute
An example circuit assignment looks like this:
A= B or C xor K.

When an identifier is undeclared its error message should be printed with the seen order left to right. To do so I attached an attribute to tIDENTIFIER and expression. At this time, it's only printing the order as it's encountered, didn't implement the function to store them yet.
A snippet of bison:
circuitDesign : assignment 
              | assignment circuitDesign
;

assignment : tIDENTIFIER tASSIGNMENT expression {if(!isDeclared($1.val)){ $1.order=1;$3.order=1;fprintf(stderr,"%d\n",$1.order);}}
;

expression : tNOT expression 
       | tLPR expression tRPR
           | tIDENTIFIER {if(!isDeclared($1.val)){ $1.order = $$.order +1;$$.order=$1.order +1;fprintf(stderr,"%d\n",$1.order);}}
           | expression tAND expression 
           | expression tOR expression
           | expression tXOR expression 
           | tTRUE 
           | tFALSE
;


and the output is 1 for each error. I don't get why it's stuck on 1. Any help is appreciated. Before incrementing the $1.order, it is always 0 even though I assigned 1 in the beginning, since its a bottom up parser the order does not yet exist I think, but shouldn't it have some implementation for inherited attributes? How to do this? Or is there a better way to print the errors in the seen left to right order?
